# Nuxt 3 - onServerPrefetch Lifecycle injection APIs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

[Vue warn]: onServerPrefetch is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.

Composable

```
const isLoggerdIn = () => {
    return expire.value //return true or false
  }
```

Middleware

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware( (to) => {
  const { isLoggerdIn } = useAuth() // composable

  if (isLoggerdIn() && to.name == 'login'){
    return navigateTo("/home")
  }

  if (!isLoggerdIn() && to.name !== 'login'){
    return navigateTo("/login")
  }

})
```

On pages home and login

```
definePageMeta({
  middleware: 'auth'
})
```

Comment: I think the issue is in `useAuth` could you add to the question the content of this util ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that when running the method `isLoggerdIn` it calls something like `useAsyncData` or `useFetch` inside of it.

If that's the case, then the error message you described would appear when calling the second method that needs to be able to access the current nuxt instance. Can only guess but in you case that's probably `navigateTo`.

In newer versions of nuxt the error message would be something more along the lines of `nuxt instance not available`. That's some well-known behaviour and is tracked in [issue #14723](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14723).

A workaround compatible with current versions of nuxt (at least until v3.3) would be to use `callWithNuxt` to call `navigateTo`.

In your example it could look like that:

```js
import { callWithNuxt } from 'nuxt/app'

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware( (to) => {
  const { isLoggerdIn } = useAuth() // composable
  
  const nuxtInstance = useNuxtApp()

  if (isLoggerdIn() && to.name == 'login'){
    
    return callWithNuxt(nuxtInstance, () => navigateTo("/home"))
  }

  if (!isLoggerdIn() && to.name !== 'login'){
    
    return callWithNuxt(nuxtInstance, () => navigateTo("/login"))
  }

})
```

I posted another example showing on how to do this [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76033170/13482004).